# How to control the style of labels in StreetViewPanorama?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, crowdflower

I need to embed some Google Maps API in a templating system I haven't full control over ([CrowdFlower](http://www.crowdflower.com/)'s), **but** the "host CSS" is breaking the styling of the labels of the streets in StreetViewPanorama, making them difficult to read. E.g. the default styling you get by using Google Street View directly is:

[image]

... but what I get is:

[image]

You can see that the "Christ Church Ln" label under the bins is barely visible.

Google API's docs [show how to style maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeStyle) but not how to do the same with [StreetViewPanorama.

I have tried "inspecting" the labels to find out the name of the class used by Google and restore it to more readable features but did not manage to find it, probably my skills are not advanced enough.

Can you help? If you want a sandbox to play with, try using my testbed [here](https://digital-contraptions-imaginarium.github.io/OLAF-yr2_lab/submission_check.html?saved=%7B%22map%22%3A%7B%22center%22%3A%7B%22lat%22%3A51.65861871%2C%22lon%22%3A-0.20163572000001295%7D%2C%22size%22%3A%7B%22height%22%3A532%2C%22width%22%3A334%7D%7D%2C%22panorama%22%3A%7B%22location%22%3A%7B%22lat%22%3A51.658645%2C%22lon%22%3A-0.20165399999996225%7D%2C%22addressControl%22%3Afalse%2C%22panoramaId%22%3A%22NsfDNKHNHr9jfyqOEV1QsA%22%2C%22pov%22%3A%7B%22heading%22%3A67.4551444234309%2C%22pitch%22%3A12.951406480667924%2C%22zoom%22%3A1%7D%2C%22size%22%3A%7B%22height%22%3A532%2C%22width%22%3A778%7D%7D%7D). Thanks.

G.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: It is not possible because the code is integrated into CrowdFlower, so it can't be minimal and not really readable. It's complete & tested. The live maps with the bad CSS styling are [here](https://tasks.crowdflower.com/channels/cf_internal/jobs/839183/work?secret=3VTW%2BhGix%2BCXBpYFnMUn10gGX2dwx2aFpEpX%2FUtr1yts). The templating I use in CrowdFlower is [here](https://github.com/Digital-Contraptions-Imaginarium/OLAF-yr2_lab/tree/0ce49da68caafe7a48b942369c463d17c4a04d0a/crowdflower/src) but it is not relevant, because the CSS is compromised "outside" of my code. My code actually does nothing.

Comment: The exercise of making the minimal example might help you identify the issue.

Comment: @geocodezip I appreciate your insistence but I believe I've explained that it is not possible to make a minimal example, because I have no control over the code that causes the issue. Some CSS setting in CrowdFlower's templates breaks the styling of the labels. I can't make a minimal example of _their_ code. What I can do - if I knew what the right APIs or styles were - is _override_ those templates. That is what I need to find out, from someone who hopefully tackled a similar issue already.